# How to adjust the sidebar position?

Tags: css, layout, sidebar

How to adjust the sidebar position? I want to remove the left space in left sidebar. How to do that? Here's the [site](http://www.homecredit.ph/2177-2/) Thank you

[image]

Comment: What left sidebar? Post a printscreen of what you want

Comment: maybe I'm too sleepy but I don't see any left sidebar. Or any sidebar whatsoever, as we're at it

Comment: Hi, pls see again the site, sidebar is now visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CSS you have assigned `1170px` for your content section and aligned with center. Change that to 100%, it will work.

```
 .ak-container
 {
   width:100%;
   margin:0px auto;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just Replace this code  in css

```
 .widget { margin: 8px -80px 25px; } .sidebar { width: 10%; }
```

Finally your sidebar will display like this:
[image]

Comment: Pls see the site again, the sidebar is now visible @Mr7-itsurdeveloper

Comment: find .widget and .sidebar class in css file.Replace your css code with this                                                         .widget {
    margin: 8px -80px 25px;
}

.sidebar {
    width: 10%;
}

Answer (score 0):

Just Use `float:left` on 
`<div id="primary" class="content-area" style="float: left;">` 
and remove 
`margin-left:150px;` from #fbuilder
[image]

Comment: Pls see the site again, the sidebar is now visible @khurram